# ZF2 - Routing, non alpha numeric characters in a segment

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

According to the ZF2 manual I should be able to use non-alpha numeric characters to seperate segments in a route:

[zf2 manual routing](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment)

I have a the following route:

```
'may_terminate' => true,
     'child_routes' => [
     'image' => [
         'type'    => 'segment',
         'options' => [
         'route'       => '/image/:id-:width-:height-:slug-:ext',
         'defaults' => [
             'controller' => ImageController::class,
             'action'     => 'image'
         ]
      ],
   ],
],
```

In my view something like this would apply:

```
/image/1-100-100-my_image.png
```

The problem I am facing is this:

When I set my route up like this:

```
'route'       => '/image/:id-:width-:height-:slug-:ext',
```

I get the following error:

> The requested URL could not be matched by routing. No Exception
>   available

If I update my router to:

```
'route'       => '/image/:id/:width/:height/:slug/:ext',
```

It works as expected.

I am using PHP7 with ZF2 version ~2.3

While I can use: / as a separator, obviously a minus sign makes more sense. What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

From manual

> The {-} after the :foo parameter indicates a set of one or more delimiters, after which matching of the parameter itself ends.

Try to add `{-}`. Because `-` is a usual symbol it's not delimiter.

And try to describe route parameters.

```
'image' => [
    'options' => [
        'constraints' => [
            'id' => '[0-9]+',
            'width' => '[0-9]+',
            'height' => '[0-9]+',
            'slug' => '[\w\d]+',
            'ext' => '\.png',
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: I am sure this will work, had some interesting issues with the skeleton translator not liking the curly braces. This was eventually solved using this notation:  'route'       => 'image/:id[-]:width[-]:height[-]:slug[.]:ext',